# Is JavaScript able to do everying Java can do in a Mule ESB project?

Tags: javascript, mule

Can you do 100% of the code in js in a Mule project? I mean that you could do all you needed to to in a typical Mule ESB project with a client, not including creating custom connectors?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not relatives, even though they share the word *Java* in their name.

Comment: I am fully aware of that, its just that I do most of my code in js these days.

Comment: I'd say no to the 100% question. You can't do all with js, not that you'll actually need to code in Java either. You should check out the scripting component for your needs: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/script-component-reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make custom code, for your transformations, or to handle some specific use cases that you can't solve with the existing components (connectors/scopes/filters/transformers), you can use the scripting component / transformer (JavaScript, Groovy, Ruby or Python). I will not assure that 100% but for the typical use cases I think you can do it with javascript.

Take a look to the documentation

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/script-component-reference